# Remove Comma method java

Tags: java

I'm trying to remove " , "- comma after my method execute. can someone help me how i can remove " , " after the method.

```
public String toString(){
    String bob ="";
    for(Person p : bcc){
        bob+= p.getName() + " is friends with ";
        for(Person fOfp : p.getFriendList()){
            bob+= fOfp.getName() +", ";
        }
        bob+="\n";  --i want to add here to remove the " , "
    }

    return bob;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The string class has a method for that, so all you have to do in your string is:

```
String.replaceAll(",", "\n");
```

Or in your case:

```
bob.replaceAll(",","\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't remove comma after it is appended. Better don't append it in the last. You can achieve it in this way,

```
public String toString(){
   String bob ="";
            for(Person p : bcc){
                bob+= p.getName() + " is friends with ";
                String comma="";
                for(Person fOfp : p.getFriendList()){
                    bob+=comma;
                    bob+= fOfp.getName();
                    comma=", ";
                }
                bob+="\n"; 
            }

    return bob;
}
```

Also don't append in String. Better use StringBuider because it is much faster and consumes less memory.